# Cross origin request error when running locally?

Tags: javascript, three.js, xmlhttprequest

Ok Im breaking down https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/03/26/exploding-3d-objects-with-three-js/ and downloaded the source, but his explanations are not in depth. Running the project locally having changed nothing, Im hit with many cross origin errors, in minified code:

> XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///Users/me/Documents/Three%20JS/examples/ExplodingObjects-master/models/heart-high.glb'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

It is also does this for various .jpg located locally. Why is this creating a cross origin problem since the file is right there?

I want to run this locally to test and understand everything, and can't run the project without the minified code. How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you running it locally? You are getting the error because you are accessing the file via the file protocol file://.

Comment: Im just double clicking the index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says that your're just opening the HTML file in your browser. Any page opened like that wont be able to do any kind of request, even to a "Local" file. You should host your page using any kind of server, apache or even this [200ok server](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb) would do the job for you.